# Clarification on handling numbers in Range & Regular Expression validator in MVC

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

MVC / ViewModel

I am having a Range and Regular Expression to validate numbers between 60.00 to 120.00

Regular expression is to validate the given number has only 2 digit decimal units.

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid.")]
[Range(60.00, 120.00, ErrorMessage = "Invalid.")]
```

However in scenario as such 98 or 100 are still a valid number. Syntax which i provided is considering it as invalid and expecting to enter the numbers as 98.00 (or) 100.00

Comment: Change the regex to make the fraction optional - `\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,2})?`

Comment: @StephenMuecke : I tried optional syntax   @"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}?"   is failing on my end. I also tried with @"\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,2})?"

Comment: What is failing? - the regex I gave allows 100, 100.0 and 100.00

Comment: code is compiling on my c# env, but page is throwing exception error saying " too many arguements "

Comment: _too many arguements_ for what?